# Can I view the configuration for the Firebase functions used by my website using Firebase/Google Cloud's UI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a new version of a web app that included some new Firebase functions. The new Firebase functions were inaccessible upon deployment.

I was able to find the root cause by familiarity with Firebase's configuration: the function requests were intended to route through the main app domain, and be redirected on the Firebase server to their final destination. (This should have been set up with Firebase's ['rewrites' section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions) of `firebase.json`, but wasn't.)

A partial view of my `rewrites` section of `firebase.json`:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/getPlaces",
        "function": "getPlaces"
      },
      ...
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

In plain English, this says, "Firebase server: every time you get a request routing to `https://my.app/getPlaces`, I want you to not route to that address within my app; I want to invoke my Cloud function instead. Otherwise, route normally."

Yet when I look at the Functions tab of my Firebase console, all I see is this:

[image: screenshot]

Under 'Request', it says `https://us-central1-my-app.cloudfunctions.net/getPlaces`. That gives me just one of the ways to access my function; the other is `https://my.app/getPlaces`, as defined in `rewrites`. I need to know all of the addresses that Firebase will respond to, not just the default one using `cloudfunctions.net`.

Is it possible to see the entire configuration for the deployed Firebase functions anywhere in the web UI, ie console.firebase.com or console.cloud.google.com, where redirects from `rewrites` like this can be seen?

Comment: You should be able to see them on the firebase console like indicated in the [image](https://imgur.com/a/KKYhFug)

Is this not working or is  it not what you meant?

Comment: That's not what I meant; I will edit the question to be a little more explicit.

Comment: @Alex: question edited